# Term For A Portmanteau of Phrases

Tags: linguistics, puns, portmanteau-words

Does "portmanteau" only refer to single words like spork or turducken? If so what would be the term for multiple phrases combined together on a common word or words?

For example:

If I wanted to call someone from this site we'd have to **"Stack Exchange numbers"**

or

The velocity of ones vehicle when trying to make it through a yellow light might be **"stoplight speed"** (this just uses a compound word)

Comment: I think that the corresponding term for a phrase is "set/fix phrase, cliche'". But the examples you make are just a combination of nouns and adjectives (noun adjuncts)

Answer (score -1):

You have tagged the category *portmanteau-words*. Then, *portmanteau-sentences* seems to be a natural analogue. You might even see *portmanteau story* [https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/portmanteau]. Portmonteau without appendage is enough to identify the overall category, IMHO, so it might be used alone to describe words, sentences etc.

> "Stack Exchange numbers"

get out :)

By the way, stop-light-speed would be just one word in german and I see no good reason against that combination, when you (and merriam webster) already wrote stoplight as a combination. You might insert dashes for clarity at will, too.

Comment: I am not sure that "Stack Exchange numbers" or "spotlight speed"  can be referred to as  portmanteaux. ***Portmanteau***:   *a word or morpheme whose form and meaning are derived from a blending of two or more distinct forms (as smog from smoke and fog)*. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/portmanteau

Comment: Yeah, they'd have to become something like  Staxnumbers and spolispeed.

Comment: @Josh: then you should make that a proper answer and see if it's accepted